# I'm trying to make a countdown application by Swift but there are few problems,

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm writing a code for a countdown application by Swift, but there are two problems.

```
let myComponetns = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear |
NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour |
NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute |
NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond ,
fromDate: myDate)
```

→At this part an error occurs and it says,
`NSCalanderUnit` has no member `"CalanderUnitYear"`

And also at this part,

```
myInt = myStr.toInt()!
```

an error occurs and it says,
Ambiguos reference to member `"String.init"`

What's the reason and can somebody tell me the solution?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

var cnt : Int = 0 
var timer : NSTimer! 
var myInt:Int = 0 

override func viewDidLoad() { 

    let myDate: NSDate = NSDate() 
    let myCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)! 
    let myComponetns = myCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear   | 
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour   | 
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | 
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond , 
        fromDate: myDate) 

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "onUpdate:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true) 
    timer.fire() 

    var myStr: String = "\(myComponetns.hour)" 
    myStr += "\(myComponetns.minute)" 
    myStr += "\(myComponetns.second)" 

    myInt = myStr.toInt()! 

} 

func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer){ 
    cnt += 1 
    let count = myInt - cnt 
    println(count) 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the `NSCalendarUnit` members are `Year`, `Month` etc., not `CalendarUnitYear`, `CalendarUnitMonth`. Also, in Swift 2, the optionset type is handled slightly differently. Try this:

```
let myComponents = myCalendar.components([.Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second],
fromDate: myDate)
```

Comment: myCalendar.components([.Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: myDate)

Comment: there still seems to be a little more problem, it seems that i haven't resolved myCalendar,

Comment: and lastly, ` myInt = myStr.toInt()! `says that it doesn't have a menber

Comment: Are you running Xcode 7 or 6? `myStr.toInt()` is gone in Xcode 7, replaced by `Int(myStr)`.